# Rails 5.2: Active Storage Variants service_url throwing "no such key" error in browser

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-s3, imagemagick, rails-activestorage, minimagick

I am using rails 5.2, active_storage with image_magic and minimagick for creating variants of different sizes, I am using the following code to generate the variants:

```rb
attachment.variant(combine_options: {
                          resize: "#{size}x#{size}^",
                          extent: "#{size}x#{size}",
                          gravity: 'center',
                          quality: 95 }
                        ).service_url
```

Variants are created successfully and loaded in browser using url generated by `service_url` method but on production is throwing following error:

[image]

**It works perfectly fine if I don't create the variants.**

Answer (score 2):

You need to call `#processed` on the variant so that Rails processes and uploads it. Rails v7.0:

```rb
has_one_attached :image do |attachable|
  attachable.variant :thumb, resize_to_limit: [100, 100]
end

def thumb_url
  image.variant(:thumb).processed.url if image.attached?
end
```

[Docs](https://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_storage_overview.html#lazy-vs-immediate-loading)